# Deduction of Modus Tollens

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was wondering what is a deduction of Modus Tollens is.

However, there are only 3 axioms that I can use to proceed on the deduction.

The 3 axioms are in the link.

[image]

Comment: The Hilbert-Ackermann system is not Natural Deduction

Answer (score 1):

Axioms I and III look immediately usable.

---

$$\begin{array}{ll}1.&\varphi&\text{as Hypothesis I}\\
2.&(\lnot\psi\to\lnot\varphi)&\text{as Hypothesis II}\\
\hline 3.&(\lnot\psi\to\lnot\varphi)\to((\lnot\psi\to\varphi)\to\psi)&\text{by Axiom III}\\
4.&(\lnot\psi\to\varphi)\to\psi&\text{using Modus Ponens (2, 3)}\\
5.&\varphi\to(\lnot\psi\to\varphi)&\text{by Axiom I}\\
6.\\7.\\8.\\9.\\
10.&(\varphi\to\psi)&\text{using Modus Ponens (5, 9)}\\
11.&\psi&\text{using Modus Ponens (1, 10)}\\
\Box\end{array}$$

$\Box$

You've just got to patch the hole in between, to show that: $$(\varphi\to(\lnot\psi\to\varphi))\to((\lnot\psi\to\varphi)\to\psi)\to(\varphi\to\psi))$$